# How to pass array index into another function in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to pass an array index into another function.

Here I have:

```
 for(i=0; i<file_cnt; i++){

          iret1 = pthread_create(&(file[i]), NULL, get_checksum, (void*)&filenames[i]);
          printf("%s\n", filenames[i]);
        }
```

In the function `get_checksum`, I eventually need the index of filenames, but `i` is not available in that function.

In the `get_checksum` function,

```
void* get_checksum(void* a){

            char *filename = (char *) a;
.....
}
```

I passed in `a` as a char pointer in relation to `filenames[i]`.

However, I need to make computations later in the function: `get_checksum`that involve getting the index of an array of sums. Therefore, I really need the index of `filenames` to be passed into the function `get_checksum` instead.

Any suggestions how to pass an array index into another function?

Comment: Create a structure, populate the structure with all the relevant parameters, and pass that in to pthread_create - http://www.amparo.net/ce155/thread-ex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd just pass 2 parameters but you can't here because `pthread_create` so you pass a pointer to a heap-allocated struct.

```
struct params {
    char *filename;
    int i;
};

/* ... */

for(i=0; i<file_cnt; i++){
      struct params *p = malloc(sizeof(struct params));
      p->filename = filenames[i];
      p->i = i;
      iret1 = pthread_create(&(file[i]), NULL, get_checksum, (void*)p);
      if (iret1) {
          free(p);
          printf("OOPS %s\n", filenames[i]);
      } else {
          printf("%s\n", filenames[i]);
      }
    }

/* ... */

void* get_checksum(void* p){
    char *filename = ((struct params *)p)->filename;
    int i = ((struct params *)p)->i;
    free(p);
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Assignment from incompatible pointer type at `p->filename = &filenames[i]`

Comment: Possible filenames is const char filenames[] ? If so than params.filename needs to be const char *.

Comment: `char **filenames` so would that syntax still apply?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a struct to pass all the parameters you need:

```
typedef struct params_s
{
    char * filename;
    int index;
    // additional params
} params_t;
```

Then either create static or allocate dinamically a variable of type `params_t`, initialize it and pass its address to the `get_checksum`:

**EXAMPLE**

```
params_t params[NUM_OF_THREADS];
...
for(i=0; i<file_cnt; i++){
    params[i].filename = &filenames[i];
    params[i].index = i;
    iret1 = pthread_create(&(file[i]), NULL, get_checksum, (void*)&params[i]);
    printf("%s\n", filenames[i]);
}
```

Comment: So I suppose you have to decide whether heap or stack allocation works for you. If the threads live past the scope of the function, bad things happen, but they might not in this case. Please note that NUMBER_OF_THREADS is not a constant so global allocation won't work.

Comment: @Joshua. You are right. But what I wrote is just an example. In my answer I wrote that the OP should either use it statically or allocate it dynamically. It's OPs choice according to the design.